# Imageview Must Focus on tapped image

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have an array like this `Image1,Image2,Image3,Image4,Image5`

Displayed that Images Randomly every time scroll horizontally to Image View.

Each An Every time generate the new series. Successfully displayed on single Image View Scroll horizontally.

```
Image2,Image1,Image3,Image5,Image4.

Image3,Image4,Image1,Image2,Image5.

Image4,Image2,Image3,Image1,Image5.
```

Now i want Image View directly displayed double tapped image.

if this is sequence of images double tapped on **Image1**

```
Image3,Image4,Image1,Image2,Image5.
```

then i want to Image View display directly **Image1** at his position
and automatically added Image3,Image4 backward.Image2,Image5. added at forward.

How may i do this thanks in advance.

I tried this one

```
   for(m=0; m<[FrontsCards count];m++)
        {
            ImgView.alpha=1;

            ImgView.tag=m;

            randIdx=arc4random()%[FrontsCards count];

            NSString *imageName=[FrontsCards objectAtIndex:randIdx];

            NSString *fullImageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",imageName];

            int padding=0;

            CGRect imageViewFrame=CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*m+padding, scrollView.frame.origin.y, scrollView.frame.size.width-2*padding, scrollView.frame.size.height);

            ImgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:imageViewFrame];

            [ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:fullImageName]];

            [scrollView addSubview:ImgView];

            [ImgView setAccessibilityIdentifier:[FrontsCards objectAtIndex:randIdx]];


            UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTapImgView:)];
            doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
            doubleTap.delegate = self;

            [self.ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:fullImageName]];

            [self.ImgView setTag:randIdx];


            [self.ImgView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];

            self.ImgView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

            NSString *imageName1=[FrontsCards objectAtIndex:randIdx];

            [newArray addObject:imageName1];

        }
        CGSize scrollViewSize=CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*[FrontsCards count], scrollView.frame.size.height);
        [scrollView setContentSize:scrollViewSize];
        [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

Comment: why do you change the tag of self.ImgView? from ImgView.tag = m to [self.ImgView setTag:randIdx];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow my logic here..

First when you Tap on any Image at that time first add that image in your another temprory `NSMuatbleArray` like bellow If possible then give the tag to every image.

```
[tempArray addObject:[yourArray objectAtIndex:selectedImage.tag]];
```

after use bellow code..

```
for (int i = 0; i < [yourArray count]; i++) 
{
        if (i != selectedImage.tag) 
        {
          [tempArray addObject:[yourArray objectAtIndex:i]];  
        }
}
```

after that use tempArray

i hope you get some idea from this logic

Comment: i mean this is your image tag which you select :)